# I am a minor with accompanied visa

Tags: visas, uk

I am a minor with accompanied visa.The parent who is displayed on a visa is traveling with me but will leave UK earlier than me.Will I be granted entry and is it a problem?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're travelling to the UK with an adult who is listed on your visa, but the adult will be leaving the UK before you. You might be asked about your arrangements when you arrive. Be sure to have a clear explanation for you living arrangements and return travel.

Comment: I have consent of both parents to travel alone but the visa is accompanied.So yes,we are entering the country together but my mother leaves earlier.